Get values from for each sheet and put values in another sheet
I am trying to get ranges from all tabs and put values in a specific tab called 'Data' at P col.
I have range values at A2:B between all tabs and am trying to get values by mapping method.
The issue is that each of the tabs values a firing increment in the array, which is why it won't be put in the data appropriately and only fires from the last tab.
Spreadsheet
I am tried:
function myFn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");
  const forSheets = ss.getSheets();
  const skip = ['Data'];
  const ssData = ss.getSheetByName('Data');

  forSheets.forEach(sheet => {
    if (!skip.includes(sheet.getName())) {
      const ssd = ssData.getRange("A2:B" + ssData.getLastRow()).getValues();
      const tabs = sheet.getRange("A2:E").getValues();
      const obj1 = new Map(tabs.map(([a, b, c, d, e]) => [`${a}${b}`, e]));
      const res = ssd.map(([a, b]) => [obj1.get(`${a}${b}`) || null]);
      ssData.getRange("P2:P").setValues(res);
      console.log(res)
    }
  })
}

There are multiple tabs, 1 called "data" and the others, and now, just for test purposes, there are values in rows:
Other tab1
[ [ 31 ], [ 62 ], [ 88], [ null ], [ null ], [ null ],]
Other tab2
[ [ null ], [ null ], [ null ], [ 998 ], [ 262], [ 129 ],]
It seems I need something like this to fix the issue or need to merge all tab arrays: How to?
Other tab1
[ [ 31 ], [ 62 ], [ 88 ], [ null ], [ null ], [ null ],]
Other tab2
[ [ 221 ], [ 998 ], [ 262 ], [ null ], [ null ], [ null ],]
In the "Data" tab, I am just getting value *only from the last tab values.

Are you trying to write only the non-null values to 'Data' so that empty values don't overwrite existing ones? Or are you trying to stack them so that all values show up in the Data sheet regardless of if they overlap in the other tabs?

Could you add expected outputs  for your first and second set of examples?

@smallpepperz,  Question updated and added a spreadsheet demo, please check now.

@sona, I noticed that some columns from the other sheets are blank in between the data. Will there be other data in these columns? Will this mean that you only need columns A, B, and E?

Merge the Data Into One Array
You can merge all the data in the other sheets by using getSheets(), map() and filter()
Script
You may refer to the sample script below:
function collectData2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = ss.getSheets().filter(sheet => sheet.getName() != "Data").map(x => x.getDataRange().getValues());
  data.map(x => x.shift());
  data1 = data.flat().map(x => x.filter((y, i) => (i == 0) + (i == 1) + (i == 4)));
  var data0 = ss.getSheetByName("Data").getRange(2, 1, ss.getSheetByName("Data").getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
  var out = data0.map(x => data1.filter(y => (y[0] == x[0])*((y[1] == x[1]))).map(z => z[2])).map(a => a.length > 0 ? a : [null])
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data").getRange(2, 16, out.length, 1).setValues(out);
}

I manually set the column to be extracted The output of this script should look like the following:

wherein I tried random samples to check if the script did search for the values based on columns A and B.
References:

getSheets()
getDataRange()
map()
filter()
shift()


Please feel free to ask anything with respect to the answer posted above.

After A1: B in the both Tabs matches, I need to merge only the E column, so I can put it in the P column in "Data" tab.

I added an update. I only included columns A and B at the beginning of the answer to show that the proper order of data is arranged accordingly.

Yes, i understand the array being merged, but can't compatible with my script. Did you try to set values?

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data").getRange(2,16,data.length,1).setValues(data); works on my side. May I know how you did it on your end?

data responds with an error. Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 0 but the range has 1.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

some times it works but mostly it giving error like this Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 296 but the range has 1.
